# C++ / JNI brace-enclosed initializer Map (Android NDK)

Tags: c++, dictionary, android-ndk, java-native-interface, list-initialization

I have an engine write in C++ to integrate with JNI in AndroidStudio.
I read & follow all tutorials I found.

In the Cpp file there is header's import which include 2 maps brace-enclosed initialized like that (just example):

The first one is initiazed with 2500 lines...
The second one is like that :

```
std::map <StateEnum, std::string> StateToString = {
  { state_one, "State 1" },
  { state_two, "State 2" },
  { state_three, "State 3" },
  { state_four, "State 4" }
};
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI     := all
APP_STL     := stlport_static
APP_CFLAGS  := -std=c++11 -fPIC
```

And here is the error :

> jni/My_header.h:line: error: could not convert '{{state_one, "State 1"}, {state_two, "State 2"}..} from '< brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map< StateEnum, std::string>'

I tried also to compile c++ file to library then integrate it to my Android project. And the result is same.

Anyone can help me. I didn't want to translate 2500 lines of map initialization (with map.add(...)) into 5000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STLport implementation is out-of-date and don't support C++11 (in particular, brace initializers). You should switch to GNU libstdc++ or LLVM libc++ implementation to get it working:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static # GNU libstdc++
# Or:
APP_STL := c++_static    # LLVM libc++
```

Comment: Thx Dmitry ! It's works great with : APP_STL := gnustl_static # GNU libstdc++